# Does parsley support data-parsley-pattern="/^[\p ... " in unicode property escapes?

Tags: parsley.js, parsley

I am using data-parsley-pattern="/^[\p{L} . .." like this. this only  a sample example, but parsley is not validating this as success, it works only with regex that is like this /^[^\d_!¡?÷?¿/\+=@#$%ˆ&*(){}|~<>;:[]]+$/ . Can anyone tell why is this and how to support unicode in Parsleyjs?

I am using data-parsley-pattern="/^[\p{L} . .." like this. this only  a sample example, but parsley is not validating this as success.

Comment: Please edit your question to use correct formatting, and include full example of regex that doesn't work.